# how to convert string to json in android. Want to pass json to server

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have facing a issue of convert string in JSON.
here is my code.

```
  private String getJsonOfArrayForOption(ArrayList<md_db_quiz> arrayListQuizForJson) {
        JSONArray jsonArrayMain = new JSONArray();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObjMain;
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayListQuizForJson.size(); i++) {
                jsonObjMain = new JSONObject();
                jsonObjMain.putOpt(Util_key.request_quiz.question, arrayListQuizForJson.get(i).getQuestion());
                //JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                Log.i(TAG, "getJsonOfArrayForOption: "+arrayListQuizForJson.get(i).getAnswer());
                jsonObjMain.put(Util_key.request_quiz.answer,arrayListQuizForJson.get(i).getAnswer() );
                jsonObjMain.putOpt(Util_key.request_quiz.explanation, arrayListQuizForJson.get(i).getExplanation());
                jsonArrayMain.put(jsonObjMain);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonArrayMain.toString();
    }
```

**output log is:**

```
getJsonOfArrayForOption: [{"checked":"0","answer":"aaaa"},{"checked":"0","answer":"aaaaa"}]

post_content: [{"question":"a","answer":"[{\"checked\":\"0\",\"answer\":\"aaaa\"},{\"checked\":\"0\",\"answer\":\"aaaaa\"}]","explanation":"aaaaaa"}]
```

**why it show "\" in asnwer object :-** [{\"checked\":\"0\",\"answer\":\"aaaa\"},{\"checked\":\"0\",\"answer\":\"aaaaa\"}]

please help me and thank you.

Comment: You're getting \" because it needs to be escaped inside ".

Comment: so who to remove that things. by that web server not ready properly

Comment: Can you post `getAnswer` method ?

Comment: @GaëtanMaisse i log get answer method its out is
getJsonOfArrayForOption: [{"checked":"0","answer":"aaaa"},{"checked":"0","answer":"aaaaa"}]